# Firestore retrieve a single document from a collection based on orderBy and limit without forEach

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

My Javascript looks similar to this:

```js
firestoredb.collection('abc')
    .doc('bcd')
    .collection('cde')
    .orderBy('bid', 'desc')
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data().bid);
        });
    });
```

Is it possible to retrieve `doc.data().bid` without the `forEach` statement and maybe without the `querySnapshot` variable? Since I know there will only be one record in this case. Or is `forEach` still the recommended way to do this? Everything else I have tried results in an error message. I am mostly wondering if there is a simpler way to code this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't fit the answer into a comment. Is this what you were looking for?

```js
firestoredb.collection('abc')
    .doc('bcd')
    .collection('cde')
    .orderBy('bid', 'desc')
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].data().bid));
```

Comment: For some reason I just get "undefined" with that, instead of a number like I got with the script in my question.

Comment: Did you remove that `limit(1)`? I can't really try it on my PC, so it's hard to tell what is the issue here :(. Maybe try to `console.log(querySnapshot, querySnapshot.docs)` etc. to figure out how returned data look like. If it's an array then you could simply use `[0]` instead of `.limit(1)`

Comment: OK yes, this gives me the correct value, without  a limit: querySnapshot.docs[0].data().bid

Comment: It also works WITH the limit. Presumably that is more efficient?

Comment: Crap, I just realized what works now is what you proposed in your answer. I don't know what was going on with it at this point. But now it seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code below helps.

```js
firestoredb.collection('abc')
  .doc('bcd')
  .collection('cde')
  .orderBy('bid', 'desc')
  .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(function(doc) {
     console.log(doc.data().bid);
   }
```

Comment: BB Design, was this helpful ?

Comment: This won't work.  A query with a limit of 1 will still give a QuerySnapshot, not a single document.

Comment: I would love to be able to do it this simply, but I got "doc.data is not a function" error in my console with this method.

Comment: Should I delete my answer then ?